# Fluent nhibernate automappings ignore inherited property

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I'm using fluent nhibernate to map following model:

```
public abstract class BasePermission : Entity
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}
public class ApproveMembershipPermission : BasePermission
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return Resources.Permissions.ApproveMembership; }
    }
}
```

I have configured to use table per class hierarchy strategy and everything works fine except one thing. I don't know how to tell FNH to igore `Name` property. Currenty I have such mapping generated:

```
<class name="BasePermission" table="BasePermissions">
    <id name="Id" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="hilo">
        <param name="max_lo">1000</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <discriminator type="String">
      <column name="Type" />
    </discriminator>
    <property access="property" name="Name">
      <column name="Name" />
    </property>
    <subclass name="ApproveMembershipPermission" discriminator-value="ApproveMembershipPermission">
      <property access="property" name="Name">
        <column name="Name" />
      </property>
    </subclass>
</class>
```

I have tried next mapping overrides:

```
public class BasePermissionMap : IAutoMappingOverride<BasePermission>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<BasePermission> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Name);
    }
}
public class ApproveMembershipPermissionMap : IAutoMappingOverride<ApproveMembershipPermission>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<ApproveMembershipPermission> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

And it leads to following mapping:

```
<class name="BasePermission" table="BasePermissions">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int64" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="hilo">
        <param name="max_lo">1000</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <discriminator type="String">
      <column name="Type" />
    </discriminator>
    <subclass name="ApproveMembershipPermission" discriminator-value="ApproveMembershipPermission">
      <property access="property" name="Name" />
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Name is still mapped in ApproveMembershipPermission class. Can anybody help with API to ignore this `Name` property?

Comment: these are pure shots in the dark; I think you should just play around with all possible options and permutations till something sticks- try having the IgnoreProperty part only in the base class, or only in the subclass; maybe try having the property in the sub class as virtual and not override...

Comment: what version of fluent nh are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it might help in your case:
[Fluent Nhibernate AutoMapping Inheritance and Ignoring an Abstract Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802956/fluent-nhibernate-automapping-inheritance-and-ignoring-an-abstract-property)

Comment: Thanks, will I will try try it a bit later. If it works, I'll accept the answer.